# Want to return inside function, but it returns without running

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

My function makes a few calls to an observer and I do not want the function to return until everything is complete. I tried putting the return inside the subscribe, but then when I call on the function I get an error since its type void without the return being the last thing.

```
 ReadyQ(){
    var isReady;
    this.Room.subscribe(snapshot => {
      if(snapshot.Ready=="true"){ 
         console.log("Ready");
         isReady =true;
      }else{
        console.log("Not Ready");
        isReady = false;
      }
  });
  console.log('ISREADY?',isReady}); //undefined
  return isReady;  //returns undefined
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Turn the observable into a promise using [`toPromise`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md), which the consumer would then hang a `then` off of:

```
ReadyQ(){
    return this.Room.toPromise().then(snapshot => snapshot.Ready === "true");
}

// consumer
this.ReadyQ().then(ready => console.log("ready is", ready));
```

This assumes that the observable emits a single snapshot value.

Comment: This may be what I am looking for, thank you. I will try this now

Comment: So are you saying that I can abandon all of my ifs and subscribes?

Comment: @BkRazor Yes I am.

Comment: Okay I am doing it your way, but the return does not seem to go through in the function. It skips right over it.

Comment: @BkRazor What return does not go through in what function?

Comment: in ReadyQ(){ return this.Room.toPromise().then(snapshot => snapshot.Ready === "true");
}

Comment: That never initiates. I even have a setInterval to check if it eventually does, but it does not. I tried =="true" and != "true" also. It never returns though

Comment: Add a `.catch(e => console.log("error", e)` clause to see if the observable is resulting in an error. Otherwise, there is a possibility the observable is never emitting a value to start with.

Comment: Yes, the promise does not exist. It is not catching an error either. I know it emits though because in my original function with the subscribe it does return the correct object.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "promise does not exist". `this.room.toPromise()` by definition results in a promise. I guess you mean the promise remains pending forever. That's unexpected behavior, so something else might be going on. You'll have to continue to debug it. try something like `this.Room.subscribe(x => console.log("emitted", x)); this.Room.toPromise().then(x => console.log("fulfilled with", x), e => console.log("errored with", e));`.

Comment: Yeah the promise is forever pending for some reason. The subscribe works 100% just can't seem to wrap my head around getting the promise to work

Comment: I wonder if it has something to with this being an AngularFire2 observable, and you said the promise returns assuming that it only returns a single value

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but looks like `Room` is an observable (rxjs). Observables are asynchronous data streams. You need to use something that allows you to await async code.

There are many ways to do this:

### Callback

```
class X {

    room: any; // Room is an "observable" ?

    readyQ(cb) {
        this.room.subscribe(snapshot => {
            if(snapshot.Ready == "true"){ 
                cb(true);
            } else {
                cb(false);
            }
        });
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.readyQ((isReady) => {
            if (isReady) {
                // ... do something
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Promise

```
class X {

    room: any; // Room is an "observable" ?

    readyQ(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.room.subscribe(snapshot => {
                if(snapshot.Ready == "true"){ 
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.readyQ().then((isReady) => {
            if (isReady) {
                // ... do something
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## Async / await

```
class X {

    room: any; // Room is an "observable" ?

    readyQ() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.room.subscribe(snapshot => {
                if(snapshot.Ready == "true"){ 
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    async doSomething() {
        var isReady = await this.readyQ();
        if (isReady) {
            // ... do something
        }
    }
}
```

Async / await is the way that looks more like your original synchronous example.

Comment: Observables already have a `toPromise` method if that's the direction you want to go.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Room` is an async observable, there is not much point in wrapping the subscribe in a promise, unless you want to change or augment its return value:

```
ReadyQ(): Promise<any> {
    let result = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.Room.subscribe(snapshot => resolve(snapshot), error => reject(error));
    }
    return result;
}

ReadyQ().then(result => {
    // do something
}).catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Is this somehow different/better than using `toPromise`?

Comment: No, @torazaburo's answer is essentially the same as mine, only smarter.